# How to get all availabel extesion properties?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

Like azure ad graph API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/functions-and-actions#getAvailableExtensionProperties

Is there any API to get all available extension properties in Microsoft graph?

Now we only can get the extension properties registered in current tenant application via /applications//extensionProperties
https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/application_list_extensionproperties

But how to get extension properties of multiple-tenant application consented from other tenant?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, we haven't exposed that particular API in Microsoft Graph.

(UPDATED 3/12/07) We've introduced an updated extensibility story for Microsoft Graph that should be a little easier to use, more discoverable and consistent across Microsoft Graph (i.e. not just for Directory entity types).  For more information check out this [blog post](https://dev.office.com/blogs/adding-customer-data-to-resources-in-Microsoft-Graph-preview).

UPDATE: New [video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Connect/2016/213) explaining our new extensibility story.  Hopefully you'll be able to get your hands on this next month.

Comment: BTW - in the video I say that this will be available in December.  Unfortunately this has been delayed until January.  Stay tuned...

Comment: Hi Dan, does this new extensibility feature release?

Comment: Yes - sorry Adam.  Yes we released this last week:  https://dev.office.com/blogs/adding-customer-data-to-resources-in-Microsoft-Graph-preview.  Updating the answer too.